# Is 'simpful' package or library?

Tags: python, package, fuzzy

When i search 'simpful' in google, they say that it is one of the library of python.
And I think so.
But my professor said me that 'simpful' is one of the package.
What is the fact?
Is 'simpful' package or library?
and Am i missing knowledge?

Comment: According to the documentation at https://simpful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, `simpful` is a library with a module that is also called `simpful`.

Comment: Package has a very [specific definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) in Python, while [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) is a generic term in computer science. `simpful` is both a package and a library.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the description on PyPi and you'll see it described as a **library**